# Unbound fields on DAC extension - where to populate?

Tags: acumatica

I have extended the CRMarketingListMember DAC in order to include a number of unbound fields.  I'm adding these new unbound fields to the List Members grid on CR204000 and need to execute some code in order to put values into these fields when the List Members grid is displayed.  The problem is that my unbound fields are always blank in the grid.  I've tried extending the CRMarketingListMaint graph and putting the code that populates the unbound fields into the CRMarketingList_RowSelected() event but that, of course, doesn't work.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

RowSelecting is the proper event in which to populate unbound fields, if doing additional BQL selects make sure to wrap the logic in a new PXConnectionScope.

Example Below :

```
    public virtual void ARInvoice_RowSelecting(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectingEventArgs e)
        {
            ARInvoice row = e.Row as ARInvoice;
            if (row != null)
            {
                using (new PXConnectionScope())
                {
                    ARRegisterExtension rowExt = PXCache<ARRegister>.GetExtension<ARRegisterExtension>(row);
                    var result = PXSelect<.....>
rowExt.UsrISExternalTax = result.IsExternalTax;
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: If you don't want to write a graph extension, you should be able to use PXUnboundDefaultAttribute on your dac field as an alternative. Advantage to the attribute is it will work on all graphs using the DAC (not just the one you are extending). Reports and GI for example. More Detail: https://help.acumatica.com/Wiki/(W(2))/ShowWiki.aspx?pageid=9657f891-5eec-949b-53ee-d700542cb03c